# Matching first column of file with awk, difficulty with quotes

Tags: bash, awk

My input file looks like this

```
Chr1 1
Chr1 2
Chr2 3
```

And I want to split the input file into multiple files according to Chr in the first column.

There should be two output files
Output file 1 (named tmpChr1):

```
Chr1 1
Chr1 2
```

Output file 2 (named tmpChr2):

```
Chr2 3
```

Here's the code so far:

```
#!/bin/bash

for((chrom=1;chrom<30;chrom++)); do
echo Chr${chrom}
chr=Chr${chrom}
awk "\$1==$chr{print \$1}" input.txt > tmp$chr
done
```

The line `awk "\$1==$chr{print \$1}"` is the problem, awk seems to require quotations around $chr to correctly match $1

`awk '$1=="Chr1"{print $1}'` works and tmpChr1 is made

`awk '$1=="$chr"{print $1}'` doesn't work either

and neither does `awk "$1=='$chr'{print $1}"`

Really struggling with the quotations, could anyone shed some light on what I should do?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Never use double quotes around an awk script and never allow shell variables to expand as part of the body of an awk script. See http://cfajohnson.com/shell/cus-faq-2.html#Q24

You are WAY off the mark with your general approach though. All you need is this awk script:

```
awk '{print > ("tmp"$1)}' file
```

Look:

```
$ ls
file
$ cat file
Chr1 1
Chr1 2
Chr2 3
$ awk '{print > ("tmp"$1)}' file
$ ls
file  tmpChr1  tmpChr2
$ cat tmpChr1
Chr1 1
Chr1 2
$ cat tmpChr2
Chr2 3
```

Any time you write a loop in shell just to manipulate text you have the wrong approach. UNIX shell is an environment from which to call tools with a language to sequence those calls. The UNIX tool to manipulate text is awk. So if you need to manipulate text in UNIX, write an awk script and call it from shell, that's all.

Comment: Thanks Ed, I've tried to look up what the greater than sign means in this case, but wasn't able to find it. Could you explain?

Comment: It means the same thing as it does in shell - redirect the output. There are small but important differences in the semantics of `>` and `>>` in awk compared to shell, though. Get the book Effective Awk Programming, 4th Edition, by Arnold Robbins.